# find /foo/bar* instead of find /foo -name "bar*"

Tags: bash

Typically it is suggested to use

```
find /foo -name "bar*"
```

to find all files starting with `bar` in `/foo`. Isn't it simpler to use

```
find /foo/bar*
```

? I understand that bash does the expansion of `/foo/bar*` in the last example instead of `find` itself, but is there any risk involved?

My use-case is that I want to store the command to `find` in a variable, e.g.

```
FINDSTRING='/foo -name "bar*"'
FILES=`find $FINDSTRING`
```

which doesn't work, or

```
FINDSTRING='/foo -name bar*'
FILES=`find $FINDSTRING`
```

which doesn't work if there is a `bar*` file in the current directory, but

```
FINDSTRING='/foo/bar*'
FILES=`find $FINDSTRING`
```

does work.

Comment: All three of the examples you've given follow bad practices and don't work reliably -- try the case where you have filenames with spaces, or, worse, a file with a name like `foo * bar.txt`. See entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 4):

Use an array to store options to a command, not a flat string:

```
find_options=( /foo -name "bar*" )
files=$( find "${find_options[@]}" )
```

There are other issues with trying to store the list of files in a string if those file names contain whitespace, but that's a matter for another question.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing whole `find` command in a variable consider storing path and glob pattern in variables like this:

```
fpath='/foo'
fname='bar*'
```

Then run your find command as:

```
find "$fpath" -name "$fname"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> FINDSTRING='/foo -name bar*'
> FILES=`find $FINDSTRING`
> ```

In this example, `bash` is expanding the wildcard (`*`) instead of `find`.  `find` so trying to evaluate a list of files as a name pattern file. So it doesn't work...

Otherwise, the `-name` option allow us to use specific pattern of name files like this for example :

```
sudo find / -name "[0-9]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

> which doesn't work if there is a bar* file in the current directory, but

You can fix this by preventing Bash from expanding the `*` in `FINDSTRING`, by using single-quotes around the argument:

```
FINDSTRING="/foo -name 'bar*'"
```

Don't let Bash do the expansion (if you do, what's the point of using `find` at all since Bash will have already produced the list of matching files?)

Answer (score 0):

`find /foo/bar*` only searches for filenames that start with "bar" at the top level of the /foo directory. For example, if /foo/quux/bar.txt exists, `find /foo -name "bar*"` will find it, but `find /foo/bar*` will not.

Now, as for storing the command in a variable, the short answer is that you can't (at least in a plain variable). There are some options to do things similar to storing it in a variable, but which one you should use depends on *why* you want to store it in a variable. [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) covers this, but here's the short summary.

- If you don't have a good reason to store the command in a variable before executing it, then just *don't*. Storing & retrieving commands can be messy, and if there's no good reason for it just skip the whole mess and execute the command directly.
- If you need to build the command dynamically, you can store a command (or just its arguments) in an array (as chepner suggested):

  ```
  find_options=(/foo -name "bar*")
  files="$(find "${find_options[@]}")"
  ```

  And as chepner also pointed out, this will fail if filenames have whitespace in them. You really should store the filenames as an array as well:

  ```
  find_options=(/foo -name "bar*")

  files=()
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      files+=("file")
  done < <(find "${find_options[@]}")

  dostuffwith "${files[@]}"
  ```

  (See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020).)
- If you just want to use the command repeatedly without writing it out every time, you can make the command into a function:

  ```
  find_bar() {
      find /foo -name "bar*"
  }

  files=()
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      files+=("file")
  done < <(find_bar)

  dostuffwith "${files[@]}"
  ```